# Error Cannot find module '@angular/material

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

Error

> Cannot find module '@angular/material

app.module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Link :https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

```
 npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

The solution that I tried

> npm update

it doesn't works.

ng --version

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 8.3.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animation: 4.0.0-beta.8
@angular/animations: error
@angular/cdk: error
@angular/common: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler: 4.3.2
@angular/core: 4.3.2
@angular/forms: 4.3.2
@angular/http: 4.3.2
@angular/material: error
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.2
@angular/router: 4.3.2
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
@angular/language-service: 4.3.2
```

- can anyone suggest me after running npm command material module stop working.

I have made working demo https://github.com/afeef1915/Angular2-Symfony3-Demo

where all code was working fine.

- any suggestion is most welcome.

Error while Installing Material

```
    D:\Angular2-Symfony3-Demo-master>npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
    npm WARN @angular/animation@4.0.0-beta.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.0.0-beta.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~4.4.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

    npm ERR! path D:\Angular2-Symfony3-Demo-master\node_modules\@angular\cdk
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! syscall rename
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Angular2-Symfony3-Demo-master\node_modules\@angular\cdk' -> 'D:\Angular2-Symfony3-Demo-master\node_modules\@angular\.cdk.DELETE'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohd\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-01T13_42_49_724Z-debug.log
```

Package.json

```
                    {
                "name": "angular2-bug-testing",
                "version": "0.0.0",
                "license": "MIT",
                "scripts": {
                "ng": "ng",
                "start": "ng serve",
                "build": "ng build",
                "test": "ng test",
                "lint": "ng lint",
                "e2e": "ng e2e"
                },
                "private": true,
                "dependencies": {
                "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
                "@angular/animations": "^4.3.3",
                "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
                "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
                "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
                "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
                "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
                "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
                "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
                "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
                "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
                "angular-datatables": "^4.2.0",
                "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
                "core-js": "^2.4.1",
                "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
                "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.3.1",
                "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
                "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
                "jquery": "^3.2.1",
                "json-server": "^0.12.0",
                "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
                "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
                },
                "devDependencies": {
                "@angular/cli": "1.2.1",
                "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
                "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
                "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.5",
                "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
                "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
                "@types/jquery": "^3.2.11",
                "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
                "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
                "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
                "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
                "karma": "~1.7.0",
                "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
                "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
                "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
                "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
                "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                "protractor": "~5.1.2",
                "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
                "tslint": "~5.3.2",
                "typescript": "~2.3.3"
                }
                }
```

Comment: Looks like material module isn't installed. When you hit npm install command, did you encounter any errors in console?

Comment: as you can see github code was working as soon i ran npm cmd then error appears

Comment: try uninstall by "npm uinstall --save @angular/material" and again install "npm install --save @angular/material"

Comment: i have update error while installing material

Comment: I've cloned your repo and successfully npm installed all. I am using npm 5.4.2. Trying updating your npm and hit npm install in a new location.

Comment: hi abdule im still using 5.4.2 D:\Angular2-Symfony3-Demo-master>npm --version
5.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Here the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21) of material 2:

its says: Angular Material now requires Angular 4.4.3 or greater since 2.beta-11

If you want the last version of material you have to upgrade to angular 5+

If you want to stick to version 4.3.2 the last you can install is 2.0.0-beta10 ( i don't recommend that )

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error and you will see that some packages need angular v.4.4.4. So I recommend you to update all @angular-packages to v.4.4.4.

Follow this steps:

1.) remove node_modules

2.) `npm cache clean`

3.) open packages.json and set the version by all @angular-packages to 
"^4.4.4"

4.) `npm install`

Comment: i have updated with cmd>npm update -D && npm update -S